# Python expecting indent Else conditional error

Tags: python

Not sure why this code isn't working. It looks like the indentation is correct.

```
count = 1
prime = 3

prime_sum_total = 0

while count != 10:
    for k in range(2,prime):  #from 2 up to but not including prime. 
        if prime%k == 0:       
            break
    else:
        prime_sum_total = prime+prime_sum_total
        count += 1
        print(prime)   #<---This is where python is saying 
    prime += 2         #IndentationError: unindent does not match any 
                       #outer indentation level
print prime_sum_total
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you post a full piece of code and explain why it isn't running as you expect? The code inside the `else` branch needs to be indented because that's how Python knows which statements are part of the `else` block.

Comment: I posted the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted works fine when I copy and paste it into a file. Most likely the problem is that your indentation for that problematic line is a mix of tabs and spaces. In your editor it might look like the same amount of indentation as the lines above it, but that depends on your tab width setting. Try making your indentation use only tabs or only spaces and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes your right, I copy pasted my own code and deleted the old code, and now it works.  I'll have to use only tabs in the future. That was driving me crazy, thank you.

Comment: @AndrewFerro Great! Yes it drove me crazy when it first happened to me :) Can you accept my answer?

Comment: @AndrewFerro I work on a very large system implemented mostly in Python.  Our practice, which I recommend you consider adopting yourself, is to set our editors to convert tabs to four spaces, and use only spaces for indentation.  The reason to avoid using tabs is that the amount of indentation per tab is not well-defined, and using spaces ensures both that (a) if it looks right, it will work, and (b) your code will look consistent whenever formatted in a monospace font.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will do that.